# Determine Rotation of Image compared to Original Image in Python

Tags: python, opencv

We have some legacy code written in C that uses GraphicMagik to manipulate an image i.e Rotate the Image
We would like to write some tests in Python to test this code, I can use OpenCV for resizing, but how do I determine if a rotation of the Image against the Original has suceeded?

Comment: What do you mean *"how can I tell if a rotation succeeded?"* Why would a rotation fail? Please show your code and how the images look before and afterwards.

Comment: Thanks for a constructive comment

Comment: You could compute the difference of the two images and look for minimum average difference.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56183201/detect-and-visualize-differences-between-two-images/56190482#56190482.