# Detect and count number of different pixels between two images with OpenCV Python

Tags: python, opencv

Similar to the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56183201/detect-and-visualize-differences-between-two-images-with-opencv-python) but I'd like to return a count of the total number of different pixels between the two images.

I'm sure it is doable with OpenCV in Python but I'm not sure where to start.

Comment: You could just try taking the difference between the images and counting the non-zero elements. You can convert the images to numpy arrays and then this becomes trivial.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This site does not serve as general problem solving portal. The community will help you to get a working solution, but you should share your code with images showing what you have done already that did not work. Read "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), "What are good topics" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and "How do I ask a good question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)?

Comment: Obtain a binary mask of each image then bitwise-xor to get the different number of pixels. Then count number of pixels on the resulting mask with `cv2.countNonZero`

Comment: _I'm sure it is doable with OpenCV in Python but I'm not sure where to start._ This isn't what Stack Overflow is for, sorry.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming that the size of two images is the same

```
import  numpy as np
import cv2

im1 = cv2.imread("im1.jpg")
im2 = cv2.imread("im2.jpg")

# total number of different pixels between im1 and im2
np.sum(im1 != im2)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use openCVs `absDiff` to get the difference between the images, then `countNonZero` to get the number of differing pixels.

```
img1 = cv2.imread('img1.png')
img2 = cv2.imread('img2.png')

difference = cv2.absdiff(img1, img2)

num_diff = cv2.countNonZero(difference)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since cv2 images are just numpy arrays of shape `(height, width, num_color_dimensions)` for color images, and `(height, width)` for black and white images, this is easy to do with ordinary numpy operations. For black/white images, we sum the number of differing pixels:

```py
(img1 != img2).sum()
```

(Note that `True=1` and `False=0`, so we can sum the array to get the number of `True` elements.)

For color images, we want to find all pixels where any of the components of the color differ, so we first perform a check if any of the components differ along that axis (axis=2, since the shape components are zero-indexed):

```py
(img1 != img2).any(axis=2).sum()
```