# OCR: Isolate handwritten text from a text document

Tags: python, opencv, ocr, handwriting-recognition

I'm working on a project that involves extracting handwritten text from a document with printed text as well. In the image below I'd like to isolate the bold black markings and identify their position relative to the rest of the image.

[image]

My project is in Python and I'm using OpenCV, but I'm open to introducing different OCR technologies into the project. Are there any tutorials or libraries/frameworks that I can achieve this with?

Comment: Do you have a copy of the original document pre being written on?

Comment: Yes. I have an image of the rubric without any text on it

Comment: Check this out, I think I would be inclined to try something like explained in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56183201/detect-and-visualize-differences-between-two-images-with-opencv-python unfortunately I can't help on the exact question

Comment: This is a great solution. Thanks!